# Is Array.Copy safe when the source and destination are the same array?

Tags: c#

I'm currently using Array.Copy to shift an array as such:

```
Array.Copy(array, 0, array, 1, array.Length - 1);
```

It's noticeable faster than using a loop. I know that similar functions in other languages (eg. memcpy) are undefined or sometimes break when the compiler gets too aggressive. Is it reasonable to consider this safe in .NET?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. It is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) how the method should behave in this case:

> If sourceArray and destinationArray overlap, this method behaves as if the original values of sourceArray were preserved in a temporary location before destinationArray is overwritten.

Comment: This is because the base function that is used is memmove, and it allows for memory overlaps.