# How may overlap happen when destination and source of CopyTo non-static method are the same array?

Tags: c#, arrays

in the [Programming C# 5](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-c-50/9781449333416/) book, I've read that:

> As well as the static Copy method, the Array class defines a nonstatic CopyTo method, which copies the entire array into a target array, starting
>   at the specified offset. This method is present because all arrays implement certain collection  interfaces, including ICollection (where T
>   is the array’s element type), which defines this CopyTo method. **Copy
>   To does not guarantee to handle overlap correctly**, and the documen
>   tation recommends using Array.Copy in scenarios where you know you
>   will be dealing with arrays—CopyTo is just for the benefit of general purpose
>   code that can work with any implementation of a collection
>   interface.

It says that overlap won't be handled correctly when using `CopyTo` non-static method. The problem is that I think ***no*** overlap may happen when we are using `CopyTo` on an array! Because, it is trying to copy **entire** array to the destination. If the destination is the same as source, destination is the same size as source, hence, the only position we can copy to is `0` ( I mean second argument must be zero: `myArray.CopyTo(myArray, 0)` ), hence, each element is exactly copied at the index, where it already is. So what is the overlap problem this book is talking about?
All I said can be seen in the code below:

```
> var a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
> a
int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }
> a.CopyTo(a, 0) // this is the only way I can call this method without 
                 // getting error, If I want to pass the same array as first argument
> a
int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }  // nothing went wrong! What is to worry about?
```

Besides the things I said, why may someone copy an array into itself at index 0? What is the point in doing that? What am I missing?

Note that this is not the same question as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149668/is-array-copy-safe-when-the-source-and-destination-are-the-same-array). That SO post is about `Copy` mehtod, not `CopyTo`. 
I think all considerations around overlapping when working with arrays,  only make sense if we pass an array to `Copy()`. As described in that SO post.

Comment: Well, what is the point of copying an array to itself? You may look at [`Array.Copy`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,d3c9a3da4e5d9327) implementation, it's done via internal call

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Array.Copy is capable of copying sub set of the array to itself, and it has lots of use cases! I'm asking about Array.CopyTo which copies entire array to itself! making to change to the array!

Comment: Here is your problem `var a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }` creates an array of length 3.
If you execute `a.CopyTo(a, 0)` it starts writing the entries of `a` on to `a` starting from index 0. so you end up writing 3 items to indices 0,1,2. But if you attempt something like  `a.CopyTo(a, 1)` this means copy elements of `a` to `a` start the process from index 1, Now you need 4 elements in `a` to perform this, Which you do not have. You only got 3.

Comment: seems like the book is wrong

Comment: @Shahryar Saljoughi I'll post an answer in a bit, keep an eye. It will explain what is going on

Comment: @SupunDeSilva yeap I know that. So again no overlap occurred! Could you give me a sample in which overlap occurs and it is not handled correctly? My point is that it can never happen to an array ! Why does the book even mention it? and suggest not to use CopyTo to avoid bad handling of overlaps? Tank you, I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: `So again no overlap occurred!` That seems like pretty clear overlap to me (since the memory space being read from and being written, and I wish I had a better word for this, overlap). Can you explain what you mean by the word `overlap` since I suspect the meaning of that word may not match with yours?

Comment: `why may someone copy an array into itself at index 0?` It is likely pointless, yes.

Comment: `// nothing went wrong! What is to worry about?` Is not inconsistent with `Copy To does not guarantee to handle overlap correctly`. The book isn't saying it won't work - it is saying that it isn't *guaranteed* to work (which the current docs don't say - so the book may, or may not, be correct).

Comment: @mjwills could you give an example in which overlap occurs and is not handled correctly? by now, I think there exists no circumstance in which this happens to an array! what about other types implementing `CopyTo` method?

Comment: `could you give an example in which overlap occurs and is not handled correctly?` No I can't. The lack of guarantees doesn't mean it won't work. It just means it isn't guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `CopyTo` call boils down to a call to `Array.Copy` in [array.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,2766). So yes, this is the same as [that SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149668/is-array-copy-safe-when-the-source-and-destination-are-the-same-array).

Comment: Did you read the question? Even if `CopyTo` wraps `Array.Copy`, it doesn't explain how an overlap may happen while using instance method `CopyTo` . overlap may happen by using `Array.Copy` but seems not correct in my case. seems the book is incorrect.

Comment: It explains how an overlap may *not* happen. You obviously got the answer already. Ask the author?

Comment: I mailed the publisher. Haven't received any answer yet.