# How can I rotate this array?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I have this code that works perfectly but in the opposite direction ( left ) I would like to rotate this array to the right, how can I do this?

```
 public int[] RotateArray(int[] A) {
    for(int i = 0 ;i < A.Length - 1;i++)
    {
       int aux = A[i+1];
       A[i+1] = A[i];
       A[i] = aux;

       // Aux = A[i];
    }
    return A;
}
```

**The result that I've got:**

```
[4,5,2,3] => [5,2,3,4]
```

**Desired result:**

```
[4,5,2,3] => [3,4,5,2]
```

Comment: Reversed of [5,2,3,4] is [4,3,2,5], not exactly your desired result though.

Comment: Did you try it? Seems like you know what to do; just do it in the other direction.

Comment: I've tried in the other direction , but it won't works ( change A[I] with A[i+1] )

Comment: @GökhanSan , what do you mean?

Comment: Save the last element in the array to a temp. Move all the rest towards the back. Set the temp as the first.

Comment: This is not reversing problem , I'm searching for a solution of an array rotation problem

Comment: I understand. `[4,5,2,3] => [3,4,5,2]`. Save the 3; move the rest one to the right; set the first to 3.

Comment: basically you want to shift all elements to the right not reverse... very known problem if you google it

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes you're right. Thank you so much!!! this works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating over the array from the back:

***Note**: I changed the method to be `void` since from the looks of it you were attempting an in-place solution anyway.*

```
using System; 

public class Program {
    public static void RotateArray(int[] A) {
        if (A == null || A.Length <= 1) {
            return;
        }
        int lastElement = A[A.Length - 1];
        for (int i = A.Length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            A[i] = A[i - 1];
        }
        A[0] = lastElement;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[] { 4, 5, 2, 3 };
        Console.WriteLine("Before: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", array));
        RotateArray(array);
        Console.WriteLine("After: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", array));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before: [4, 5, 2, 3]
After: [3, 4, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to shift the last to the first position, you can (mis)use Array.Copy, with source and destination referring to the same array.

```
int[] arr = { 4, 5, 2, 3 };
var last = arr[^1];
Array.Copy(arr, 0, arr , 1, arr.Length -1);
arr[0] = last; // -> now 3, 4, 5, 2
```

Comment: Probably not ["mis"-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149668/is-array-copy-safe-when-the-source-and-destination-are-the-same-array)?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I had thought source and destination array being the same array would throw or mess up data, but turned out it works.
Maybe if you left-shift you get data loss. Seems some C-function internally, maybe just a block copy...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using Linq if you wish to go that route. (Note: No error checking but will work for arrays with at least one element).

Essentially you leverage Linq to get the first (N - 1) elements and prepend the last one.

```
var original = new int[] { 4,5,2,3 };

var rotated = 
    original
    .Take(original.Length - 1)
    .Prepend(
        original.Last())
    .ToArray();
```